# ajax, javascript, php not working perfectly

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

While trying to create a registration page using PHP, JS and ajax, I run into errors that is due to the JS codes that I wrote and the reason for saying that is because without the ajax and JS codes, the PHP codes works perfectly.

This is the steps that I took, I wrote the HTML codes first and this is the HTML codes. It is called add.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title id="title">jQuery Insert</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/styles.css'>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="ball">
            <form action="" method="post" id="theForm">
                <p><input type="text" id="f_name" name="f_name" placeholder="firstname" value="></p>
                <p><input type="text" id="l_name" name="l_name" placeholder="lastname" value="></p>
        </section>
        <p><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
        </p>
        <p id="success"></p>
        <p id="error"></p>
        <p id="statusT"></p>
        <p id="stat"></p>
        <!--<script src="js/insert.js"></script>-->
        <script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
        <script src="js/add.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then I  create the ajax.js script

```
function getAjaxRequest(){
    var ajax = null;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    if(window.ActiveXObject){// Older IE
        ajax = new ActiveXObject("MSXML.XMLHTTP.3.0");
    }
    return ajax;
}
```

After this, I create the JS script

```
var f_name = document.getElementById("f_name").value;
var l_name = document.getElementById("l_name").value;
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");

var ajax = getAjaxRequest();

ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4){
        if((this.status == 200 || this.status < 300) && this.status == 304){
            document.getElementById("success").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            form.submit.disabled = true;
        }else{
            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            document.getElementById("statusT").innerHTML = this.statusText;
            document.getElementById("stat").innerHTML = this.status;
        }//End of status

    }//End of readyState

}//End of ajax.onreadystatechange
ajax.open("POST", "/../../jquery/ajax/addStudent.php");

   var data =new FormData();
   data.append('f_name', f_name);
   data.append('l_name', l_name);

submit.addEventListener('click', function(){
   ajax.send(data);

}, false);//end of addEventListener
```

And finally, this the PHP script

```
<?php
// Set the database access information as constants:
DEFINE('DB_USER', 'willpower');
DEFINE('DB_PASSWORD', 'arseblog');
DEFINE('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE('DB_NAME', 'school');
// Make the connection:
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
// Set the character set:
mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $sqlistu = "INSERT INTO students (`first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES
        (?,?)";

        $queryistu = $dbc->prepare($sqlistu);
        //echo $db->error;
        $queryistu->bind_param("ss", $f_name, $l_name);
        $queryistu->execute(); 

        $IDnum = mysqli_insert_id($dbc);

        // Free result set
        $queryistu->close();
        ///////////////////////////

        if (isset($IDnum)):
            echo 'success' . '<br>';
            echo $IDnum;
        endif;
}
```

While checking the NETWORK of the firefox developer edition browser under XHR and under RESPONSE, it shows the success message which was set to show

> document.getElementById("success")

which was set to the

> responseText

of ajax even before filling the form

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> submit.addEventListener('click', function(){
>    ajax.send(data);
>
> }, false);//end of addEventListener
> ```

You have a function which you call when `submit` is clicked, which sends the data via XMLHttpRequest.

However, you **collect** all the data outside of that function.

That code **doesn't** wait until the button is clicked, so the data is collected immediately (i.e. before the user has typed it).

Comment: when the whole code was in addEventListener, it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myForm = document.getElementById("theForm");

var ajax = getAjaxRequest();

ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4){
        if((this.status == 200 || this.status < 300) && this.status == 304){
            document.getElementById("success").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            form.submit.disabled = true;
        }else{
            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            document.getElementById("statusT").innerHTML = this.statusText;
            document.getElementById("stat").innerHTML = this.status;
        }//End of status

    }//End of readyState

}//End of ajax.onreadystatechange
ajax.open("POST", "/../../jquery/ajax/addStudent.php");



myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
   e = e || window.event;
   e.preventDefault();
   var f_name = document.getElementById("f_name").value, l_name = document.getElementById("l_name").value, data =new FormData();
   data.append('f_name', f_name);
   data.append('l_name', l_name);
   ajax.send(data);

}, false);
```

Comment: Why should the OP ___try this___? **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I totally agree with you, but, the reason that made me just post the code as is, without explanations, is that at the time when  I decided to answer I was using my mobile phone, seems strange isn't it ? I talk about me, you really can't imagine how painful is to post using a phone, sometimes I write some words and suddenly they just be erased ! I don't even know why nor how that happened, sometimes I try to delete a letter but It doesn't work. That's why I just answered without explanations. I really appreciate your opinion, if that really matters I can, happily, delete the answer.

Comment: @this. I will try it

Comment: @jaquarpow  I'm here for any further explanations you want.

Comment: @this when I checked the XHR params it now displayed the firstname and lastname but it still does not submit it to the database, while it submit to the database using PHP and HTML only. What still remains for me to do to learn AJAX, JS and PHP fully?

Comment: did you tried `var_dump($_POST)` to see what's inside.